# How to move a div from inside a div to right under it on small screens using bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t10lX.jpg)
I have a div(div1) containing another div(div2)
I want to know how to move div1 to under div2 on small screens
I am using bootstrap4

I tried to use row and col classes but it didn't work

(  (div2)      )<---- div2 inside div1
i need:
(div1)
(div2) on top of each other

Edit:

```
<div id="div1" style="background:url("sdic/sdv.jpg") center no-repeat cover;">
 <div id="div2">
  Some content
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the div2 to go under div1 and div will stay with the background image inside

Comment: So, you mean nested columns? I think you should draw some paints because I didn't understand what you are trying to **draw**.

Comment: i a div inside another div

Comment: i want the to be on top of each other on small screens

Comment: post your code..

Comment: You can't move a child outside its parent without dom manipulation using JavaScript. If you're talking about presentation rather than document structure (i.e., if you're using DIV to refer to visual things on the screen and not strictly the elements of the document's hierarchy), that's a piece of cake. But it's not clear whether you mean you want to alter the structure of the document or you want it to just look like X is inside Y in this context and not in that.

Comment: checkout this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/BFIfY3O3j8Pp3mzAQLMD?p=preview. It should work if your scenario is as simple

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Is this an attempt to put a caption or a heading on top of an image, but then display below on small viewports? Is the background image only serving to display an image, or is there other content? I think you're getting bad responses because the ultimate goal isn't clear.

Comment: In other words, you're asking how to make your attempted solution work rather than how to solve the underlying problem Read about XY problems here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/380533

Comment: @denmch I added an image hope it clarifies my problem

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to introduce another div inside div1. On screen sizes bigger than 425px, it will have its normal ordering. Less than 425px, the order will flip.

edit: updated the answer so that it doesn't need the custom CSS. You can use bootstrap 4 d-flex and order classes to achieve the same result. This will also use bootstraps breakpoints.

(Use the CSS provided if without bootstrap)

```css
.div1 { display: flex; flex-flow: column; }
.div3 { order: 1; }
.div2 { order: 0; }

@media (min-width: 425px) {
  .div3 { order: 0; }
  .div2 { order: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1 d-flex">
  <div class="div3 order-2 order-sm-1"><h3>Div3</h3></div>
  <div class="div2 order-1 order-sm-2"><h2>Div2</h2></div>
</div>
```

```
.div1 { display: flex; }
.div2 { order: 2; }
.div3 { order: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to have a parent container with two direct children, one a picture element with appropriately sized images, and the other a block level element (a div is fine).

The basic markup might look something like this (resize your browser to see the effect):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.splash {
  height: 20em;
  position: relative;
}

.splash img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 40.1em) {
  .splash {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .splash > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left; 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .splash > .modal {
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,.2);
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 20%;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="splash">
  <picture>
    <img src="//unsplash.it/1600x900" />
  </picture>
  <div class="modal">
    <p>Form goes here/</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It may be a little tricky to spot at first given the simplicity of the mockup, but the modal sits on top of the img element on larger viewports, but not on smaller ones. You'd want to flesh it out and adjust the sizing per your requirements.

You would want to put more image sources in the picture element to load image appropriate to the screen. Sorry I can't give more detail, but I have to run to a meeting, and it's a pretty simple approach that's framework agnostic. I don't think there's a built-in solution for this in Bootstrap as it's not a super common feature, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and happend to be working

Css:

```
  /****HEADER START****/
  #header .header-background{
   background: url("../images/header.jpg");
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .header-background{
    background: none !important;
  }
 .header-img{
    display:block !important;

 }
  .form-container{
    display:none;
  }
  .form-container2{
    display: block !important;
  }
}
/****HEADER END****/
```

html:

```
   <div class="container-fluid header-background">
    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <img class="d-none img-fluid header-img" src="images/header.jpg"/>
         <div class="form-container">
          <img class="img-fluid"src="images/unkownbrand.png" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, iure.</p> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, eveniet?</p>
           <form>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" />
           <input type="text" class="form-control" />
           </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-container2 d-none">
  <img class="img-fluid"src="images/unkownbrand.png" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo, iure.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, eveniet?</p>
  <form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to use media query for small screens, for example

```
    @media (max-width: 801px) {

   div1 {position: relative;}
   div2 {position: absolute; top: -80px (adjust it as you want) };

}
```

This should work.

Comment: is their a way using bootstrap4?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to add top-margin on child div in mobile view

**https://plnkr.co/edit/edrz9fQeRHqL1jPqV2Ri**

```
<style>
.div1{
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.div2{
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .div2{
      margin-top: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div2">    
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's a good way but i need to know if their is a way doing it using bootstrap 4